# Glass material denoising problem in Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, glass

I modeled a wall light, which you can see in the images. I created a studio environment and rendered that. However i couldn't figure out why glass material looks worse when denoising is applied. Is the problem caused by my render settings or glass material itself or something else?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "smudging" effect of the Denoiser will probably disappear when you use more *Render Samples*; 200 for refractive Glass Lenses is maybe a bit low. Try raising the samples a good bit, maybe in steps of 100, and re-render. Repeat a few times until you get there.

*Also:* I assume that you have good resons to cancel out the shadows in your glass material? Because they affect the rendering quite a bit. This only has a minor impact on your main problem, but still it's something to keep in mind when troubleshooting. :-)

[image]
Left: Your Shader. Right: Principled BSDF, 100% Transmission, 0% Roughness.

Comment: thanks for reply :) i tried what you said, still i've same problem, it didn't worked. thank you for your helps:)

Answer (score 0):

if you turn off caustics, that should lower the noise, though it doesn't really work if you want caustics.
have you tried using denoising normal and albedo in the compositer?[image]